# sed / Batch / Windows: Prevent changig Backslash to slash

Tags: windows, batch-file, replace, sed

I have a variable with a path, like this:

```
SET "somevar=D:\tree\path\nonsens\oink.txt"
```

And I have a file, where somethink like this is written

```
VAR=moresonsense
```

Now I want to replace the word `morenonsense` to `D:\tree\path\nonsens\oink.txt`. This should be the result

```
VAR=D:\tree\path\nonsens\oink.txt
```

For this, I am using the tool sed for windows. But using sed in windows gives me the following:

```
VAR=D:    ree/path/nonsens/oink.txt
```

The spaces between the colon and `ree` is a tab. I thought, I could fix it with the following line before calling sed:

```
SET "somevar=%somevar:\\=\\\\%"
```

But no, this line is not working. So I have some questions:

1. Is there a possibility, to prevent sed from changing \t to a tab and prevent changing two backslashed \ to a slash /?
2. Is there another easy way to replace a string with another string within a file with BATCH?
3. Does someone has another idea how to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not `\`-escape the `\` instances *in the variable expansion*; use the following:

```
SET "somevar=%somevar:\=\\%"
```

I don't know whether that solves all your problems, but `SET "somevar=%somevar:\\=\\\\%"` definitely does not work as intended, because it'll only match *two* consecutive `\` chars in the input, resulting in a no-op with your input.

Comment: Ok, that's a shame. Your suggestion is the solution!